# Symlinked executable can't find dependencies

Tags: linux, symlink

**OS.:** Ubuntu 22.04

**Scenario**

In the Home folder I created a folder called `bin`. In this folder I clone the GitHub repositories I need.

For example, I cloned [this golang repository](https://github.com/devploit/dontgo403) in my bin folder (the bin folder is in Home).

**repository location:** /home/focus/bin/dontgo403/

1. I created a symbolic link called check403 so it can be used from any location:

   cd /usr/local/bin

   sudo ln -s ~/bin/dontgo403/dontgo403 check403

Check that the symbolic link has been created correctly:

```
readlink check403

/home/focus/bin/dontgo403/dontgo403
```

2. I navigated to the Home folder `(~)` to launch the program from a different location than where it is installed:

```
    cd ~    
    check403 -u example.com
```

Output:

```
2023/01/01 13:38:43 open payloads/httpmethods: no such file or directory (This folder and these files are its dependencies located in the folder where it is installed > `~/bin/dontgo403`).
```

3. According to the program description (repository), if I use the `-f` parameter (to specify the location) everything works as expected:

```
check403 -f ~/bin/dontgo403/payloads -u example.com
```

**My question is:** How can I run the program without always specifying the location of its dependencies, for example: check403 -u example.com (without specifying each time: `-f ~/bin/dontgo403/payloads`).

In this scenario it is possible with the -f parameter, but I have encountered other scripts/programs that have not declared a location parameter, so they always have to be run from the location where they are installed.

Comment: Hm, what kind of program is that? Dependencies being in the same directory as the executable is not how Linux programs are usually invoked.

Comment: It is a Pentesting program that checks if blocked resources (403 Forbidden) on your server can be accessed by manipulating the URL address.

Comment: I mean what kind of language does it use? Do you need to compile it? Install it? This sounds like you actually need to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. You are deploying directly to ~/bin, albeit in a sub-folder implying that this is only intended to be run by a single user, yet you are creating a symlink in /usr/local/bin o expose this to all users, even though they should not have permission to access you ~/bin

Dependencies paths are identified by different means in different languages - relative to the executable / from LD_PATH / from a setting in a configuration file / from a predefined location ....

Rather than creating a symlink to expose the executable, wrap it in a simple shell script in /usr/local/bin or ~/bin :

```
#!/bin/bash

~/bin/dontgo403/dontgo403 $@
```

or add an alias.

Comment: Thank you @symcbean!